# xcode 4.2 build and archive issues in iTunes

Tags: ios, xcode4

i have upgraded my xcode to 4.2 and tried to build my old project using new xcode. 
i changed the following settings in new xcode -

**Architectures -> armv6 armv7**

**Base SDK - ios5**

**Compiler - > LLVM GCC 4.2**

**iOS Deployment Target -> iOS 3.1**

i was able to build and install it in device(5.0 ios) but when i tried to make an distribution build using archive, it failed to install in the devices showing invalid entitlements both for ios4 and ios5.

when i googled it i found that in order successfully intall set

**Build Active Architecture Only - > NO**

After this i got success to install my distribution build .ipa through iTunes in iphone 3gs/4(both 4 and ios5) but it still showing invalid entitlements in iphone3g(3.1.3ios).
i have static libraries in my project as well.

Please help me figure out how to create an build which should install in 3.1 to 5.0 ios.

Thanks

Comment: Did you check that your provisioning profiles are setup correctly for release build?

Comment: yes i have checked that they are fine. i am trying to create an distribution build and  created .ipa build is installing successfully in iphone 3gs/4 but failing only in 3g with ios 3.1.3 device.

Answer (score 1):

You will have to plug your device and open organizer, than it will ask to install IOS3.0 - 3.2.2 Device Debugging Support, install it and try again, it works for me.

Comment: That's about distribution as well, not only debug. Are you sure installing debug-support resolved the distribution build problem for you ?